# Trim variable-length tensor to a maximum length

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

Having a 2-dimensional tensor with one fixed dimension and one variable-length dimension: how can I limit the variable-length dimension to a maximum length? If the variable-length is shorter then the maximum it should just be kept (*and not padded*), but if it is longer it should just cut of the end.

For example, assume all tensors have the shape `(None, 4)` and I want to get all of them limited to a max shape of `(3, 4)`. One example input could be:

```
tensor1 = tf.constant([
    [1, 2, 0, 0],
    [1, 3, 4, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [7, 7, 7, 7],
    [7, 8, 9, 1],
], dtype=tf.int32)
```

..., which should get trimmed to:

```
tensor1_trimmed = tf.constant([
    [1, 2, 0, 0],
    [1, 3, 4, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
], dtype=tf.int32)
```

However, anything smaller then the maximum should stay untouched:

```
tensor2 = tf.constant([
    [9, 9, 9, 9],
    [9, 9, 9, 9],
], dtype=tf.int32)
```

...should stay exactly the same:

```
tensor2_trimmed = tf.constant([
    [9, 9, 9, 9],
    [9, 9, 9, 9],
], dtype=tf.int32)
```

Is there any built-in command to do that? Or how would you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice) supports numpy-style slicing, so you can use `[:3,:]` in your example

```
>>> tensor1 = tf.constant([
...     [1, 2, 0, 0],
...     [1, 3, 4, 0],
...     [0, 0, 0, 0],
...     [7, 7, 7, 7],
...     [7, 8, 9, 1],
... ], dtype=tf.int32)
>>> tensor1[:3,:]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)>
>>> tensor2 = tf.constant([
...     [9, 9, 9, 9],
...     [9, 9, 9, 9],
... ], dtype=tf.int32)
>>> tensor2[:3,:]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[9, 9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9, 9]], dtype=int32)>
```